# Duplicate Class Name In a Directory

Tags: linux, grep, find, command

suppose i have 3 files say :

1. lib/model/lib/1.class.php

   ```
   class A { }
   ```
2. lib/model/store/2.class.php

   ```
   class A { }
   ```
3. lib/model/lib/abc/3.class.php

   ```
   class A { }
   ```

can i write some grep command that can solve the same.

i searched but it doesnt work

find . -name '*.class.php' | xargs basename | sort | uniq -d

Comment: what do you want? the duplicated `class A` or the files that containing dup class names?

Comment: @Kent both would be best..... but if u can give any of the two... still i will be very thank full

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking by "_solve the same_". You provided sample input - adding sample output would help.

Answer (score 0):

If your file names don't contain spaces:

```
$ awk '/class/{class2files[$2] = class2files[$2] FILENAME FS}
END {
    for (class in class2files) {
        n = split(class2files[class],files)
        if (n > 2) {
            print "class:", class
            for (i=1;i<n;i++) {
                print "\tfile:", files[i]
            }
        }
    }
}' $(find . -name '*.class.php' -print)
```

If they do then set IFS to '\n' in shell before the command.

Comment: If you provided more information than "not worked at all" then we could help you figure out how to fix it. Did you try adding some print statements to try to debug it or just throw up your hands in despair? If the former, tell us what the problems seem to be. If the latter, oh well...